# Center text in div having a div inside of it

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #afafaf;background-color:#efefef;width:100px;height:14px;">
    <div style="text-align:center;width:50px;height:14px;background-color:green;">
        50%
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i put the 50% in the middle if the 1st DIV , the 2nd div might have width of 0 to 100 px (progress bar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/6BvS7/)

- I added `position: relative` to your outer div.
- I added a new text div, which is absolutely positioned over the progress bar.
- See http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Whatever `width` your progress bar has, it won't affect the text div.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="border:1px solid #afafaf;background-color:#efefef;width:100px;height:14px;position:relative">
    <div style="text-align:center;width:50px;height:14px;background-color:green;"></div>
    <div id="text">50%</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example have a third div with `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto` which centers this div into the middle